# Can I create folder type structure of models in Django admin?

Tags: django-models

Let's say I have model **User** and I want to create 2 different models **ActivateUser** and **DeactivateUser**.

[image: Folder structure]

So, in the admin portal once user click **User**, 2 respective models should appear, then user can any of the models to see fields.

Is it possible to achieve?

I tried inline, but it is displaying all the fields of both models in one page. But I want something like folder type structure.